# Treating missing values in sentiment analysis

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a medium-sized dataset of encrypted comments and their corresponding labels, which is either of positive or negative. I wonder what the best way is to treat the missing comments given that the missing comments rate is 1%. Below is a toy example of the dataset after applying an extensive data cleaning step.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'comments':['xxy uuicz', '', 'jiko bhht'], 'label':['positive', 'negative', 'negative']})
```

I am using Gensim (preprocess_string) and removing stopwords through building a customized list of stopwords. The goal is to fit a classifier to predict the sentiment of any given encrypted comment.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific in what you are doing, with what libraries, and what your goals are. Without that, no one can offer you an actual answer and at best will only give their opinion, which isn't what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: I don't really see you having many options. If you can't reconstruct the missing comments somehow, then you either have to delete all the missing comment instances from your model, or (probably the more preferable route), map them to two dummy "empty (positive)" and "empty (negative)" variables for downstream modeling.  The latter scenario is probably better if there is any residual information carried in the sentiment label alone.  However if you are only trying to create a model that maps input words -> output sentiment, then you can just delete the missing instances.

Comment: Delete the observation. There is no information that you can derive from your input/features to help you run your sentiment analysis.

Comment: @nicolasgervais The issue with this approach is that it might not be desirable in production.